# Why calling AForge library function causes AccessViolationException in C#?

Tags: c#, access-violation, aforge

The following code causes access violation exception - why is that? Can I call AForge filters from inside `unsafe` block?

```
unsafe
{
    BitmapData bmd = ThresholdedImage.LockBits(boundingR, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, ThresholdedImage.PixelFormat);
    BitmapData bmda = intersectResult.LockBits(
        new Rectangle(0, 0, intersectResult.Width, intersectResult.Height),  
        ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,  
        intersectResult.PixelFormat);


    intersectResult = intersectFilter.Apply(bmd); //causes exception here
    ImageStatistics st = new ImageStatistics(intersectResult);
    area = st.PixelsCountWithoutBlack;

    intersectResult.UnlockBits(bmda);
    ThresholdedImage.UnlockBits(bmd);
}
```

Comment: does it cause an exception or an access violation? It cannot be both

Comment: @sehe: It says "AccessViolationException was unhandled" so it has to be possible.

Comment: Thx. That would mean: you get the exception. When dealing with unmanaged code, an access violation is entirely possible and looks like **[this](http://img262.imageshack.us/img262/7761/mediamonkeyerror.png)**

Comment: Since this looks like it is gathering Tumbleweed now, I suggest to post more code (a minimal working - i.e. crashing - example or perhaps a link to your project; this will make it easy for people without knowledge of AForge to chip in)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to track down this issue.

Can you confirm that your boundingR region does not indeed represent the whole image ?

You will get this exception because at some point on AForge side there is an unmanaged copy of bytes that mistakenly uses the `Stride` value of the **full** image.

I believe filters that derive from `BaseInPlacePartialFilter` will work with image regions, but filters based on `BaseInPlaceFilter` will most likely have the issue.

If it's feasible you may apply the filter on the whole image and then copy back just the region you are interested in…

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found another way to do it and the problem does not seem to appear anymore. But I will try to test your suggestion.